# the chatterbot's response function doesn't work as i thought

Tags: python-3.6, chatterbot

so i was combining discord bot with chatterbot.
i tried to get a response from the bot using `get_response()` function and i used it like
`response = bot.get_response(input)`
but it seems like it just only accepts input from the console and not string input. if i enter from console, it does put the result in the response string.
i haven't got any errors.

i have searched about it a lot and so far i haven't found anything useful.

any ideas? (also if you want to see the whole code, ask me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
input_adapter = 'chatterbot.input.VariableInputTypeAdapter',
```

Rather than:

```
input_adapter = 'chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter'
```